# Как объектам фильтров добавить свойство disabled: true

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Изучаю Express.js и не могу ни как понять как объектам  фильтров добавить свойство disabled: true если при добавлении этого фильтра к уже выбранными  не будет товаров с  данным набором характеристик.

База данных PostgreSQL orm sequelize.js

связи: одна Models к многим  Product. один Product к многим Specification

```js
const { Product, Models, Specification } = require('../models/models');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

class productController {
    async getAll(req, res) {
        const { subCategoryId, models, specifications, minPrice, maxPrice } = req.query;
        if (!subCategoryId) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'subCategoryId is required' });
        }
        const modelCondition = models ? { model: { [Sequelize.Op.in]: models.split(',') } } : {};
        const specificationCondition = specifications
            ? { specification: { [Sequelize.Op.in]: specifications.split(',') } }
            : {};
        const priceCondition = {};
        if (minPrice && maxPrice) {
            priceCondition.price = {
                [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    { [Sequelize.Op.gte]: minPrice },
                    { [Sequelize.Op.lte]: maxPrice },
                ],
            };
        } else if (minPrice) {
            priceCondition.price = { [Sequelize.Op.gte]: minPrice };
        } else if (maxPrice) {
            priceCondition.price = { [Sequelize.Op.lte]: maxPrice };
        }

        try {
            const products = await Product.findAll({
                where: { ...priceCondition },
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Models,
                        where: { subCategoryId, ...modelCondition },
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ['updatedAt', 'createdAt', 'img', 'subCategoryId'],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        model: Specification,
                        where: { ...specificationCondition },
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: [
                                'updatedAt',
                                'createdAt',
                                'productId',
                                'specificationGroupId',
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ['updatedAt', 'createdAt'],
                },
            });
            res.json(products);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching products by subcategory ID:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching products' });
        }
    }

    async getOne(req, res) {}
}

module.exports = new productController();
```

Контролер получения фильтров

```js
const { SpecificationGroup, Specification, Models } = require('../models/models');

class FiltersController {
    async getAll(req, res) {
        const { subCategoryId, models, specifications } = req.query;
        const specification = await SpecificationGroup.findAll({
            where: { subCategoryId },
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Specification,
                    attributes: ['id', 'specification', 'value'],
                },
            ],
        });


        const uniqueSpecifications = specification.map((group) => {
            const uniqueSpecs = group.specifications.reduce((acc, spec) => {
                const exists = acc.some((item) => item.specification === spec.specification);
                if (!exists) {
                    acc.push(spec);
                }
                return acc;
            }, []);

            const plainGroup = group.get({ plain: true }); // Получаем "плоскую" версию объекта
            return {
                ...plainGroup,
                specifications: uniqueSpecs,
            };
        });
        const model = await Models.findAll({
            where: { subCategoryId },
        });

        res.json({
            specifications: uniqueSpecifications,
            models: model,
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new FiltersController();
```